# How can i get variable's value from servlet in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've read a lot about the same question, I tried to follow the answers but it never work.

I have a servlet name: get_import.java
I have a jsp name: import.jsp

First, in processRequest(), i initiated a String s = "abcdef", then i wrote:

```
s=request.setAttribute("validate", s);
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("import.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Then, in import.jsp, i wrote:

```
<%  String st = (String)request.getAttribute("validate");
    out.println("<h1>Result: " +st+ "</h1>");
%>
```

Then output was:   Result: null

I can't explain why the variable's value is null in jsp, please help me to solve this problem or find other way out. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: can we see your web.xml file?

Comment: What does the processRequest() method do ? I don't see any reason why the string won't print ? I am sure the string is not set as attribute

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options:

1.Store it in the session.

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
if (username != null && username.length() > 0) 
{
 session.setAttribute("username", username);
}
```

2.Store it as a hidden field in the form.

```
<input name="filter" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

3.Store it in a cookie.

```
username = getCookie(userCookieName);

// Get from cookie.
 function getCookie(name) {
    if (document.cookie) {
           index = document.cookie.indexOf(name);
           if (index !== -1) {
           f = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
           t = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
             if (t === -1) {
               t = document.cookie.length;
               }
             return(document.cookie.substring(f, t));
           }
      }
 return ("");
}
```

4.Not really another option but a mechanism - pass it in the URL:

```
.... onclick="window.location = 'details.jsp?filter=...'
```

Comment: I want to use cookie as your third way but please tell me why the result is null, i tried your first way but the result still null.

Comment: The **First** point shows to create the session.

To retrieve the session value you need to use following code
    session.getAttribute("usrename").toString();

Answer (score 0):

try storing the value in session like this way

```
session.setAttribute("validate", s);
```

Then, in import.jsp, :

```
<%  String st = (String)session.getAttribute("validate");
    out.println("<h1>Result: " +st+ "</h1>");
%>
```

**One side note** try avoiding writing java in jsp pages.Best alternate is [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)/[EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it but it has same result. I think the problem is not in code.

Comment: This problem doesn't relate to my project because i created another Web application just to test this code, and it didn't work too. I'm thinking about the file web.xml, do i have to configure this file?